# How to bind three events to the same function in Jquery or jJavascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard-events, jquery-events, event-binding

Can anyone explain how can three events can be bind to same function ? i.e. same function should be called when the following events happen.

- window unload.
- on pressing 'ESC' button.
- on clicking 'close' class.

I have written function on clicking '.close' class in following way:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var starttime = new Date(start);
    $(".close").click(function () {
        jwplayer('mediaplayer').stop();
        end = new Date().getTime();
        endtime = new Date(end);            
        $.ajax({ 
          url: "/courses/136",
          data: {'timeSpent': endtime - starttime},
        });
    });

  });
</script>
```

The same thing should happen for `window.unload()` and on pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> button. Is there any Jquery method for this.

Answer (score 3):

Create a function that is responsible for handling the events and then you just have to pass that function to every event you want to execute it.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    var starttime = new Date(start);

    var eventHandler = function (event) {
        jwplayer('mediaplayer').stop();
        end = new Date().getTime();
        endtime = new Date(end);            
        $.ajax({ 
          url: "/courses/136",
          data: {'timeSpent': endtime - starttime},
        });
    };

    $(".close").click(eventHandler);
    $(window).on("unload", eventHandler);
    $(document).on("keydown", function(e) {
        if (e.which == 27) {
            eventHandler(e);
        }
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Please post *complete* answers rather than posting half-answers and then editing in the complete version later.

Answer (score 2):

You just define the function:

```
function handler() {
    jwplayer('mediaplayer').stop();
    end = new Date().getTime();
    endtime = new Date(end);            
    $.ajax({ 
      url: "/courses/136",
      data: {'timeSpent': endtime - starttime},
    });
}
```

...and bind it three times; for the ESC key part you probably want a wrapper:

```
$(".close").click(handler);
$(window).on("unload", handler);
$(document).on("keydown", function(e) { // Or whatever element is relevant
    if (e.which == 27) {
        handler.call(this, e);          // With the above, just `handler();` would work too
    }
});
```

Comment: @BhojendraNepal: You don't *have* to (see the comment). You'd only need to use `call` if the handler used `this` (which this one doesn't), and you only have to pass `e` if the handler usees it (which this one doesn't). But this is showing the general case of ensuring the handler you're chaining to has a consistent environment when you call it.

Answer (score 0):

The functions that you pass to jQuery methods like `.click()` don't have to be anonymous. You can refer to a function by name. So:

```
function yourFunction() {
   // do your jwplayer and ajax thing here
}

$(window).on("unload", yourFunction);
$(".close").click(yourFunction);
$(document).on("keyup", function(e) {
  if (e.which == 27)
    yourFunction();
});
```